# Get fb post with tags

Tags: php, facebook

I'm developing a Facebook app in PHP and I have a little problem with sending posts on my own wall, fill message tagged friend and post, back when I read post id I get that friend in with_tag field, but when I that post with link I don't get back tagged friend - why ?

```
 $story = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', array( 
          'message' => 'test', 
          'tags' => $_POST['tag'], 
          'place' => '195383960551614',
           'link' => 'www.developers.facebook.com'
        ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();
```

sending post like this problem if I put link field  don't get back from post field with_tags, without link field I do

```
$post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/'.$story[id].'/?fields=with_tags' ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

 $post[with_tags] == NULL  //why ? ??
```

`$post[with_tags]` result is null, but I have tagged friend in post.
I need to know why adding field link in post changed that I'm not getting a with_tags field?

Comment: Your `link` value is invalid, it needs to be a full, absolute URL.

Comment: link works in 'link' => 'www.developers.facebook.com' , but problem is  i not get a with_tags in post result